# Typescript is complaining I am not using undefined as return type

Tags: typescript, generics, undefined

Trying to understand why I need an 'undefined' as part of my return statement, when in method 'p' I check to make sure either oldData or newData exist.

```
interface List {
    name: string;
    desc: string;
}

interface Sand {
    dot?: string;
}


type DifferenceComparison<U> = (oldData?: U, newData?: U) => U | null;

const user = {
    name: 'super',
    desc: 'cool',
}

// Typescript is complaining I am not returning an 'undefined'
const p: DifferenceComparison<List> = (oldData, newData) => {
    if (!oldData && !newData) {
        return null;
    }

    // When newData or oldData is true assign the data that exist.
    const redLines = newData ? newData : oldData;

    return redLines;
}

console.log(p({name: 'aa', desc: 'aa'}));
```

Comment: Actually the compiler is complaining that you *are* returning an `undefined` - which is true in case the function is called with an `undefined` as first argument, but a `List` as second argument

Comment: @UnholySheep - thanks for your response. I added an extra check in method 'p'. Trying to understand after I do the check still ask me to return undefined.
**bold**
   // When newData or oldData is true assign the data that exist.
   ` const redLines = newData ? newData : oldData;`

Answer (score 0):

@UnholySheep is right. The error is saying that you might be returning `undefined` which is unacceptable.  Typescript thinks that there is a possibility that `oldData` could still be `undefined` when you are returning it at the end.

You already checked this with `if (!oldData && !newData)`, but typescript can't understand this as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) when you put the two together.  If you check each value separately, it properly narrows the type of both variables and the error goes away.

```
const p: DifferenceComparison<List> = (oldData, newData) => {
    if (!newData) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!oldData) {
        return null;
    }

    // When newData or oldData is true assign the data that exist.
    const redLines = newData ? newData : oldData;

    return redLines;
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAM5mQbwLABQyxyIcAthAFzJZSgDmA3IScgCYQYI12MsEAvoUKhIsRCgDKcEO1ysS7APZgA-LzD0QzQsIIiCYAJ4AHFABFgMGNAggkAYWXlTcehmUgAPAFUAfMgAvMgAFMoANuwWcGBwGsi%20ADSkEADuMXEJvgCUwYG%20yAA%20pACuEREChAheWMilGNDBCkQkZJQ0AOQYpeZQnUmKxJzcXTWRA3qGAPTTyAAqZlwI9KbYmMg1rhFwoIzIAJLIFKSqyFAQYKVQIPuyyJ2lchAwoBDsndW12KY0VjZ2BwQZyudyYLzedBYQIhcJRTJwFIgdIIvJBQL4VrEaxhACEyIysTgeUxbDYFyuNzKFQEbH0bBxoVxkWiRJJQzJFOuIGplQ5%20g5s2QAHUABb2VKEuLIZRQGXwonIDZaUooOAYDDABg8sDijiK3WxZAQAAemDAADoOTUQHULux0MiMM0CQjkGpJW6aCyEVUsedLtyAw63hgBAKCDbPBEIBaIsoGKFTKEcKQKNQHnA4AMOMsulnOshBDkckwgA)

But you could shorten it down to

```
const p: DifferenceComparison<List> = (oldData, newData) => {
    return newData || oldData || null;
}
```